# call sub to change USERname color

Tags: vb.net

I want to change USERname color inside RitchTextBox, I am using this code below to call the SUB but all the text now in red?

UPDATE

```
Sub AddMessage(txtUsername As String, txtSend As String)
    box.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    box.AppendText(vbCrLf & txtUsername & "$ ")
    box.SelectionColor = Color.Black
    box.AppendText(txtSend)
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdSend.Click

    ' Shell("net send " & txtcomputer.Text & " " & txtmessage.Text)


    Try
        If txtPCIPadd.Text = "" Or txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtSend.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("wright a message!", "MsgBox")
        Else
            client = New TcpClient(txtPCIPadd.Text, 44444)
            Dim writer As New StreamWriter(client.GetStream())

            txttempmsg.Text = (txtSend.Text)
            writer.Write(txtUsername.Text + " @ " + txtSend.Text)
            AddMessage(txtUsername.Text, txttempmsg.Text + vbCrLf)
            'txtmsg.Text="You:" + txtmessage.Text)
            writer.Flush()
            txtSend.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace the box.Text = .... line with a call to your AddMessage Sub.

Comment: not work too i change it to this AddMessage("txtUsername", "txttempmsg") now when i send a message to myself i got this in chat box txtUsernameJAMES-PC :hi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a problem trying to get something to work in your program. It is easier to create a test example that you can then use to figure out what is happening without dealing with a lot of other variables in your larger program. In your case I created a VB Winforms app, added a RichTextBox, two TextBox's and a Button. By doing so I am able to show that the function is working.

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub AddMessage(txtUsername As String, txtSend As String)
        box.SelectionColor = Color.Red
        box.AppendText(vbCrLf & txtUsername & " :") 'Note added colon
        box.SelectionColor = Color.Black
        box.AppendText(txtSend)  'Note changed variable name to parameter name
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AddMessage(txtUsername.Text, txttempmsg.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: I like your idea, ok let me do that to see what happen really :) thanks Mark

Comment: duplicate command the problem from these 2 lines, now it's work when i send Hi, appers in black and username in red but only for 2 seconds, writer.Write(txtUsername.Text + " : " + txtSend.Text)
                AddMessage(box.Text + txtUsername.Text, txttempmsg.Text + vbCrLf)

Comment: you do not need to add the box.Text or the VbCrLf  to your parameter inputs for the AddMessage Subroutine they are already part of it. Appending adds the new text to the existing text

Comment: vbCrLf I add it to make the second message in new line,I figure this: when I send "Hi" to myself User name in red and the message in black, but when i receive the message almost in 2 seconds, all the text appears in red. everything the first and second line in chat box

Comment: are you using the same AddMessage sub for both the sent and received message?

Comment: Of course i am not using it for send & receive, if i do that i will only be listing to myself, I think i must right other SUB for receiving command line! writer.Write(txtUsername.Text + " : " + txtSend.Text)

Comment: That's not what I am saying, you should be using the same subroutine for both the send and receive processes. If you are writing to your richtextbox directly by assigning to box.Text you are overwriting your formatting.

Comment: I made update to the main Code in my question so you can see the code better, the section of "$" sign work but the second section of "@" duplicate the "$" section, so as you said receive command is the problem, how can i add AddMessage to receive too?

Comment: I see your sending code, where is your receiving code? looking at your previous code it looks like it is your listener which is being read in your timer1 code make sure that you are using AddMessge and not writing directly to your richtextbox there too.

Comment: I made the same thing to receive in timer1 with SUB2 and everything work now, did you know i spend week on this :D! i don't know how to thank you, you are awesome